# using a string resource in a Toast

Tags: java, android, toast, charsequence

My code is:

```
public static void ToastMemoryShort (Context context) {
    CharSequence text = getString(R.string.toast_memoryshort); //error here
    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
    }
```

but I'm getting "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context" in Eclipse. I'm trying to get ready for localising my app (getting all the hard coded strings into resources), so where I have:

```
getString(R.string.toast_memoryshort)
```

I previously had a hard coded string which was fine.

I'm not sure what's going on here (Java noob). Can anyone enlighten me please?

Many thanks

Baz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this instead:

> makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration) Make a standard
>   toast that just contains a text view with the text from a resource.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: Actually, it was a combination of your answer and Rasel's: Needed the .show on the end, didn't need Rasel's ""+ before the resource ID: Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_memoryshort, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); so +1 to Rasel too. Many thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Change to

```
 public static void ToastMemoryShort (Context context) {

        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.toast_memoryshort), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
        }
```

Comment: The reason this answer is so much popular is that using `getString` in the first place suggests that string itself was needed for some reason (var injection, formatting etc.). Plus, it actually resolves the exception in question which is a genuine value.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your toast more generic like this:

```
public void toast(String msg){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = msg;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Then just call when you need like this:

```
toast( "My message hardcoded" );
```

or by referring to  strings.xml   like this:

```
toast( this.getString(R.string.toast_memoryshort) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to get the desired output:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.exit_survey_toast),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

replace **exit_survey_toast** with your string value.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
CharSequence text = getString(R.string.toast_memoryshort); //error here
```

for:

```
CharSequence text = context.getString(R.string.toast_memoryshort);
```

The `getString` function is implemented in [Context#getString(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int))