# Android Toast cannot be resolved as field or type

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've done some research on the above error and it would seem that to solve there are two ways most people do:

1. Re import R
2. Close and restart eclipse

However I have done both and yet I still get the same error. Does anyone know of any other ways to defeat this error?

I'm thinking though that it may be my code. I'm trying to compile the bluetooth le sample found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BluetoothLeGatt)

I've brought over everything yet I'm still stuck with 36 errors with most of them being this cannot be resolved as field or type error.

Here is how they call the toast line:

```
 Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And there strings.xml found in the values folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">BLE Sample</string>
    <string name="ble_not_supported">BLE is not supported</string>
    <string name="label_data">Data:</string>
    <string name="label_device_address">Device address:</string>
    <string name="label_state">State:</string>
    <string name="no_data">No data</string>
    <string name="connected">Connected</string>
    <string name="disconnected">Disconnected</string>
    <string name="title_devices">BLE Device Scan</string>
    <string name="error_bluetooth_not_supported">Bluetooth not supported.</string>

    <string name="unknown_device">Unknown device</string>
    <string name="unknown_characteristic">Unknown characteristic</string>
    <string name="unknown_service">Unknown service</string>

    <!-- Menu items -->
    <string name="menu_connect">Connect</string>
    <string name="menu_disconnect">Disconnect</string>
    <string name="menu_scan">Scan</string>
    <string name="menu_stop">Stop</string>
</resources>
```

I'm literally a day into my first android development and this is all new to me. I thought using the sample code they would provide would help me get a good over view of how the bluetooth system works.

Can anyone help me beat this error?

I should add that every item on this list has an error. Any time I call anything with R.string. it get the same error. 
Logcat since 1:25pm:

```
09-06 13:25:20.901: E/(526): W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiAdapter::enableData(int): default implementation invoked
09-06 13:25:20.901: E/(526): W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiAdapter::setAPN(char*, int): default implementation invoked
09-06 13:25:20.911: D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(25851): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "SOL2", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-06 13:25:20.921: D/GCM(2565): GcmService start Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
09-06 13:25:21.051: D/ConnectivityService(526): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=0
09-06 13:25:21.542: D/Tethering(526): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
09-06 13:25:21.642: E/(526): W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiAdapter::enableData(int): default implementation invoked
09-06 13:25:21.642: E/(526): W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiAdapter::setAPN(char*, int): default implementation invoked
09-06 13:25:21.662: D/GCM(2565): GcmService start Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
09-06 13:25:22.102: D/ConnectivityService(526): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100
09-06 13:30:01.245: V/DigitalWidgetViewsFactory(6453): DigitalWidget sets next alarm string to null
09-06 13:36:19.083: I/ActivityManager(526): No longer want com.google.android.talk (pid 26303): empty for 1801s
09-06 13:36:31.455: V/BackupManagerService(526): Running a backup pass
09-06 13:36:31.455: V/BackupManagerService(526): clearing pending backups
09-06 13:36:31.455: V/PerformBackupTask(526): Beginning backup of 1 targets
09-06 13:36:31.485: V/BackupServiceBinder(526): doBackup() invoked
09-06 13:36:31.485: D/PerformBackupTask(526): invokeAgentForBackup on @pm@
09-06 13:36:31.495: I/PerformBackupTask(526): no backup data written; not calling transport
09-06 13:36:31.506: D/PerformBackupTask(526): starting agent for backup of BackupRequest{pkg=com.android.providers.settings}
09-06 13:36:31.506: D/BackupManagerService(526): awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{4202bfe0 com.android.providers.settings}
09-06 13:36:31.506: D/BackupManagerService(526): agentConnected pkg=com.android.providers.settings agent=android.app.backup.BackupAgent$BackupServiceBinder@42081138
09-06 13:36:31.506: I/BackupManagerService(526): got agent android.app.backup.BackupAgent$BackupServiceBinder@42081138
09-06 13:36:31.506: D/PerformBackupTask(526): invokeAgentForBackup on com.android.providers.settings
09-06 13:36:31.516: V/BackupServiceBinder(526): doBackup() invoked
09-06 13:36:31.526: W/SettingsBackupAgent(526): Couldn't backup /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt
09-06 13:36:31.526: I/PerformBackupTask(526): no backup data written; not calling transport
09-06 13:36:31.526: I/PerformBackupTask(526): Backup pass finished.
09-06 13:39:59.999: I/ActivityManager(526): No longer want com.google.android.music:main (pid 26385): empty for 1849s
09-06 13:40:00.099: W/ActivityManager(526): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.music/.playback.MusicPlaybackService in 5000ms
09-06 13:40:05.134: I/ActivityManager(526): Start proc com.google.android.music:main for service com.google.android.music/.playback.MusicPlaybackService: pid=27303 uid=10041 gids={50041, 3003, 1015, 1028}
09-06 13:40:05.214: I/MusicStore(27303): Database version: 70
09-06 13:40:05.274: D/dalvikvm(27303): GC_CONCURRENT freed 315K, 4% free 9097K/9448K, paused 3ms+9ms, total 39ms
09-06 13:40:05.274: D/dalvikvm(27303): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
09-06 13:40:05.284: D/dalvikvm(27303): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
09-06 13:40:05.364: D/SystemUtils(27303): getSystemProperty: lpa.decode=null
09-06 13:40:05.364: D/CacheService(27303): onCreate
09-06 13:40:05.374: D/CacheService(27303): onBind
09-06 13:40:05.384: I/LocalDevicePlayback(27303): Streaming client created.
09-06 13:40:06.445: D/dalvikvm(27303): GC_CONCURRENT freed 181K, 3% free 9337K/9580K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 30ms
09-06 13:40:06.535: I/MediaStoreImporter(27303): Update: incremental Added music: 0 Updated music: 0 Deleted music: 0 Created playlists: 0 Updated playlists: 0 Deleted playlists: 0 Inserted playlist items: 0 Deleted playlist items: 0 Removed orphaned playlist items: 0
09-06 13:40:10.459: I/MusicLeanback(27303): Conditions not met for autocaching.
09-06 13:40:10.459: I/MusicLeanback(27303): Stop autocaching.
09-06 13:40:20.549: D/GCM(2565): Ignoring attempt to send heartbeat on dead connection.
09-06 13:40:59.997: I/ActivityManager(526): No longer want android.process.acore (pid 26550): empty for 1807s
09-06 13:45:01.283: V/DigitalWidgetViewsFactory(6453): DigitalWidget sets next alarm string to null
09-06 13:48:16.403: I/EventLogService(2565): Aggregate from 1378470317827 (log), 1378469896229 (data)
09-06 13:48:16.533: I/ServiceDumpSys(2565): dumping service [account]
09-06 13:50:23.497: I/jdwp(24586): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
09-06 13:50:23.507: I/jdwp(20948): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
09-06 13:50:34.378: D/dalvikvm(526): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3407K, 27% free 23292K/31488K, paused 11ms+8ms, total 146ms
09-06 13:52:43.224: D/ChildProcessLauncher(5790): Setting up connection to process: slot=2
09-06 13:52:43.224: I/ActivityManager(526): Start proc com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process2 for service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService2: pid=27469 uid=99002 gids={}
09-06 13:52:43.244: I/ChildProcessService(27469): Creating new ChildProcessService pid=27469
09-06 13:52:43.254: D/ChildProcessLauncher(5790): on connect callback, pid=27469 context=2105709408
09-06 13:52:43.254: I/LibraryLoader(27469): loading: chromeview
09-06 13:52:43.304: I/LibraryLoader(27469): loaded: chromeview
09-06 13:52:43.304: I/chromium(27469): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(72)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
09-06 13:52:43.314: D/TraceEvent(27469): View tag enabled: false
09-06 13:52:43.334: I/chromium(27469): [INFO:child_process_service.cc(132)] ChildProcessService: Exiting child process.
09-06 13:52:43.344: W/ChildProcessConnection(5790): onServiceDisconnected (crash?): pid=27469
09-06 13:52:43.344: D/ChildProcessLauncher(5790): stopping child connection: pid=27469
09-06 13:52:43.344: I/ActivityManager(526): Process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process2 (pid 27469) has died.
09-06 13:52:43.344: W/ActivityManager(526): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService2 in 5000ms
```

Comment: Can you check and make sure if you haven't imported the android.R? If yes, then remove that import.

Comment: You should be using the same R file that is present within your project.

Comment: Ok i found the R file that my app has, but how can I get it to use my strings values?

Comment: Can you try to use Toast.Length_Long instead of Toast.Length_Short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Typically, all *R.string.stuff* cease to be errors after you build the project because the file R.java is generated during the build. If you have not yet built the project, they are shown as errors and this is normal. By the way, in Eclipse, you can manually delete the error messages in the error message window (you can select and delete one or several errors, but cannot delete the root node that reads "Errors (N items)"). One more "magic" pass is pressing F5 ("Refresh") when the project is selected in the "Package Explorer" (the left-hand) pane.

2) Make sure that the generated R class belongs to the same package as the class where it's used. In Eclipse you must see in the "Package Explorer" pane: *YourProject*--gen--*your.package*--R.java.
(If that file does not exist, is the folder read/write?)

3) It may be easier to create an empty project and move the google sources to it than try to compile the project from git. At least some google app projects use a directory structure that is different from what you normally get with Eclipse (because they are built with a special script).

Answer (score 1):

Try to show Toast like this:

```
 Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here context refers to context of current Activity where you showing the Toast.

See these as well: [Toast.makeText from resource string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152709/toast-maketext-from-resource-string)

[Android: Java: using a string resource in a Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331793/android-java-using-a-string-resource-in-a-toast)

Answer (score 0):

Generally when there are any errors in the resource folder , the R.Java file doesnt get created properly and as a result you will get this sort of error . Please check whether you have any errors in the layout folder or drawable folder.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getText(R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

U can use:

`String str = getResources().getText(R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported).toString();`

Comment: [makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) is there since API level 1, should be no problem.